# Drop year from datetime object in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

I have the following timestamped dataframe in python:

```
   timestamp     value_A
-------------------------
 5/3/16 8:00          64
 5/3/16 9:00          74
5/3/16 10:00          54
5/3/16 11:00          34
5/3/16 12:00          26
5/3/16 13:00          42
5/3/16 14:00          44
5/3/16 15:00          14
5/3/16 16:00          65
5/3/16 19:00          36
5/3/16 20:00          32
5/3/16 23:00          32
...
```

I want to drop the year from the `timestamp` column. And so I want to produce this dataframe with these timestamps, just leaving the month, day, and hour:

```
   timestamp     value_A
-------------------------
    5/3 8:00          64
    5/3 9:00          74
   5/3 10:00          54
   5/3 11:00          34
   5/3 12:00          26
   5/3 13:00          42
   5/3 14:00          44
   5/3 15:00          14
   5/3 16:00          65
   5/3 19:00          36
   5/3 20:00          32
   5/3 23:00          32
...
```

What I have tried is to first convert the `timestamp` column to a `datetime` object with:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])
```

and then use the `dt.strftime()` function to drop the year with this, just leaving day, month, hour, and minute:

```
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%D:%m:H%:M%')
```

However, this still leaves in the year. How can I drop the year so that I just have the order of day/month/hour/minute?

Comment: try %d instead of %D?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
df['timestamp_dt'] = df['timestamp_dt'].dt.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')
```